# ImageTk.PhotoImage not displaying image correctly

Tags: python, tkinter, tiff, python-3.9

I want to show a .tif file in a tkinter gui, but I have been having trouble getting the images to load properly. I was able to view the image correctly using Image.open with mode='r', but then when I call ImageTk.PhotoImage it displays a blank white canvas. Here is the code:

```
def func(image_paths):
    root = Tk()
    im = Image.open(image_paths[0], mode='r')
    im.show()  # shows image correctly
    im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    im_label = Label(image=im)
    # im_label = Label(image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image_paths[0], mode='r')))  # This doesn't work either
    im_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    root.mainloop()
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue with my sample TIFF image.

Comment: Hmmm. My tif files are only two dimensions which is why I think it's having issues.

Comment: Please provide a link to the tiff file you're trying to open so we can test properly.

Answer (score 0):

So, what ended up working was the solution in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6l6HDQyWdH0
The lines of code that got it to work was:

```
curr = Image.open(image_paths[0], mode='r')
curr = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cm.jet(NormalizeData(np.array(curr).astype(np.float64)))*255))
curr = ImageTk.PhotoImage(curr)
```